# Use a simple constructor in a Mybatis project can not work correct

Tags: java, mybatis

Recently I wrote a Mybatis demo to study Mybatis, it's function is just simplest CRUD. But I find that if I add a field Constructor below, the codes just can not work.

```
public class User {
    ...

    public User(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    ...//getter and setter
}

public void add() throws IOException{
    ...
    int insert = session.insert(statement, new User(-1, "mike", 20));
    ...
}
public void testGetUser() throws IOException{
    ...

    User user = session.selectOne(statement, 5);
    ...
}
```

Comment: what do you mean add and what do you mean "just can not work" ?

Comment: Please provide an explicit description of your problem. Is there a compile error; a runtime exception; unexpected behavior? From just looking at it, your code looks correct; so we need more information in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `User` class should have a default constructor and getter-setter methods for all mapped properties. You can add any other constructor to it but keep the default constructor.